# Amazon S3 service ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection from pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, timeoutexception

When i work with s3 on Amazon, I keep getting the ugly ConnectionPoolTimeoutException.

The problem is that due to the front end of the application, i can not close the opened s3 objects before front end is done with them so i have implemented this solution :

```
@Autowired
private AmazonS3 s3client; // credentials are set properly.

private static List<S3Object> openedObjects = new ArrayList<S3Object>();

// initialize bucket :
private String bucketName = "myShinyNewBucket";
private synchronized boolean initBucket(){
    try{
        Boolean exists = null;
        try{
            exists = s3client.doesBucketExist(bucketName);
        }catch(Exception e1){
            System.out.println("\n\n\tToo many opened objects ; closing...\n\n");
            deleteOpenedS3Objects();
            exists = s3client.doesBucketExist(bucketName);
        }
        if(exists!=null){
            if(!exists){
                s3client.createBucket(new CreateBucketRequest(bucketName));
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("\n\n\tFailed to initialize bucket.\n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}

private synchronized void deleteOpenedS3Objects(){
    System.out.println("\n\tClosing opened objects...");
    try{
        for(int i=0 ; i<openedObjects.size() ; i++){
            openedObjects.get(i).close();
            openedObjects.remove(i);
        }
    }catch(Exception e1){
        System.out.println("\tCould not close all opened s3 objects, only the first "+i);
    }
    System.out.println("\tTrying again :\n\n");
}

// GET :
public final String getFromAWS(final String amazonName){
    S3Object s3object = null;

    if(initBucket()){
        try{
            try{
                s3object = s3client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, amazonName));
            }catch(AmazonClientException e){
                deleteOpenedS3Objects();
                s3object = s3client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, amazonName));
            }
            openedObjects.add(s3object);
            return s3object.getObjectContent().getHttpRequest().getURI().toString();
        }catch(Exception e1){
            if (((AmazonS3Exception)e1).getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_NOT_FOUND){
                System.out.println("\n\nNo such object in bucket.\n");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("\n\n\tCould not read bject from bucket.\n\n");
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Yet, the exception is still happening.

```
org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection from pool
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.leaseConnection(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:286) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$1.get(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:263) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor144.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionRequestFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionRequestFactory.java:70) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.8.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy188.get(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
...
```

Only when i do ctrl+c in console, does it get to the part where it is closing the opened s3 connections :

```
... Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: Operation interrupted
        at org.apache.http.pool.PoolEntryFuture.await(PoolEntryFuture.java:142) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar!/:4.4.4]
        at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool.getPoolEntryBlocking(AbstractConnPool.java:306) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar!/:4.4.4]
        at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool.access$000(AbstractConnPool.java:64) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar!/:4.4.4]
        at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool$2.getPoolEntry(AbstractConnPool.java:192) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar!/:4.4.4]
        at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool$2.getPoolEntry(AbstractConnPool.java:185) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar!/:4.4.4]
        at org.apache.http.pool.PoolEntryFuture.get(PoolEntryFuture.java:107) ~[httpcore-4.4.4.jar!/:4.4.4]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.leaseConnection(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:276) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$1.get(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:263) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor144.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
        at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionRequestFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionRequestFactory.java:70) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.8.jar!/:na]
        at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy188.get(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:190) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
        ... 148 common frames omitted


        Too many opened objects. // <-- This is where it catches it.



        Closing opened objects...
        Could not close all opened s3 objects.
        Trying again :




        Failed to initialize bucket.
```

Again, I am unfortunately not in a position where i can close opened s3objects before i leave the functions in my s3-client class. The only hope i have had, was to wait until TimeoutException happens, catch it, then closing all opened objects and trying again. 
However, i can't seem to catch it in the right place.

Please, help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

We must use [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) whenever we are dealing with any type of file read or write. This will auto close the resources used, even if we face any sort of exception.

**In My case :** I was getting 404 while reading from *S3* for bulk operation, which i ignored while writing script by logging the error and forget to close the connection in finally block.

**Example snippet:**

```
static String readFirstLineFromFile(String path) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader br =
                   new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
        return br.readLine();
    }
}
```

**Note:**

1. Try with resources have support from *JDK 8* and above.
2. All the resources declared in `try()` must implement the `AutoCloseable` interface.

Answer (score 0):

I think the sollution is to catch and process the ugly TimeoutException in my @ControllerAdvice class. I have done so and so far i have not had it happen in the app. I'll post a confirmation once i'm sure.